# How to get rid of the parts that stick out when the end of a line intersects another line in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image]
Here's an image that describes what I mean. The cap of the line segment sticks out when the line segment ends right next to a different line, and I was wondering if there's a good way to make it flush using Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're using the 'Triangle in/out' shape setting from the toolbar of the drawing tools.

Inkscape automatically adds the 'Power Stroke' path-effect to your path to achieve this style. That means that, while in node-editing mode, you can simply move the pink diamond-shaped handle that controls the thickness of the 'Power Stroke' effect a little backwards so it tapers off at the end.

[image: Stroke with the handle moved so it tapers off]

If you don't like that line-cap style, then you can open the 'Path → Path Effect...' panel and set the 'End cap' (or 'Start cap') to 'Round' for example.

[image: Same stroke with the 'End cap' option set to 'Round']

By the way, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click, then drag these nodes to add more of them and fine-tune the thickness of the stroke along the path. Clicking them while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> opens a little dialog where you can set the position and thickness precisely and a <kbd>Alt + Ctrl</kbd>-click deletes them again.

[image: Same stroke but with three 'Power Stroke' handles with varying thickness]

Admittedly this is only to make it less visually obvious. To truly get what you want, you'll probably have to use 'Path → Object to Path' (or 'Stroke to Path') and manually edit the nodes at the ends. Or cut those parts off with some helper objects and using 'Path → Difference'.